# magento newsletter sent in queue but not received by email

Tags: php, linux, email, magento, cpanel

I have a weird situation regarding sending of newsletter. I created a sample newsletter and send it to subscriber, however, these newsletters were not received by subscribers but **mark SENT to the newsletter queue**.

2 weeks ago, one email subscriber receive all the testing newsletter but not all subscriber receive these newsletter only this email.

**Problem:**

Emails are stuck anywhere on the internet but marked sent to the newsletter queue.

Only one email receive the testing newsletter but we have three sample email subscriber.

Does anyone experience this? or What was the problem?

This is my cronjob settings on the server.

> */5   *   *   *   * php -f /home/sample/public_html/directory/cron.php

**Update**:credit to @ryantxr.

I'm not sure if this is the email log but I can see on the result that the email was not sent.

This is the error from my server

> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO::
>   450 4.1.8 : Sender address rejected:
>   Domain not found

**Update:**
I have no idea how to solve this. @ryantxr mentioned that I am sending to invalid domains. i only touched cronjob and no other things has been set up.

Comment: Are the emails going to spam?

Comment: @ryantxr there were no email on the spam or inbox.

Comment: Emails do not "get stuck somewhere on the Internet".   Have you checked the logs of the email server to see if they got sent out?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the email logs but try to look at my update

Comment: Why are you sending email to a non-existent domain?

Comment: What email are you using to receive newsletter? have you checked on your spam? If you are using gmail, emails are divided in to three, primary, social, promotion.

Comment: @Tyler Thanks! I'm using gmail. I didn't expect that the newsletter were in promotions.